# Kill a smart contract where my funds are currently stuck inside

Tags: solidity, remix, smart-contract-wallets, frontrunning

I am the owner of the contract however I didnt write it but have some funds stuck inside, when i try to withdraw or run the contract the remix IDE tells me that "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart contract". I have no idea what to do or how to know if the funds are actually still within the smart contract.
I would like to know if there is a way to... 1. check the funds arent lost or been moved out.
2. Look at my options for bringing them out of the SC

Comment: 1. Put the contract address in etherscan (or a block explorer for the blockchain you used) 2. We need the contract code.

Comment: Unless the contract has a withdraw function or an upgradability feature in it won't be possible. Contracts cannot do something they weren't programmed to do. Contracts cannot be modified once they were deployed.